# How do I get a tmux session's base directory?

Tags: shell-script, tmux, terminal-multiplexer

I have been using `tmux` for a few months, and there is one thing that always bothered me: when I type `cd` into my shell, I get moved into my home directory (this is the standard behavior of `cd`, so nothing unexpected).
What I would like to have is that I get into the current tmux session's base directory, and this could probably easily be implemented via a shell function:

```
cd () {
   if [ $# -eq 0 ]
   then
      command cd $TMUX_BASE_DIR # fictional environment variable
   else
      command cd $@
}
```

However, I have not found a way to find this directory. tmux does not have a build-in command apparently nor sets an environment variable. I also skimmed over the man page, but didn't find anything in the `COMMANDS` or `VARIABLES` section. This directory needs to be saved somewhere though, as opening a new tmux window makes it go to this directory.
Of course one I open a new window and close one everytime I want to achieve the desired behavior, but this is surely less than optimal and there needs to be a better way.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior / get the session base directory in tmux? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

My tmux(1) manual documents a `session_path`, so maybe you could save it with something like this "tmux path session report" script:

```
#!/bin/sh
TMPFILE=`mktemp /tmp/tps-report.XXXXXXXXXX` || exit 1
tmux run "printf '#{session_path}\n' > \"$TMPFILE\""
cat "$TMPFILE"
rm $TMPFILE
```

Also your `$@` probably should be written as `"$@"`.

Comment: When I execute `tmux run "printf '#{session_path}\n'`, it outputs a single `n` and exits. Also my tmux(1) manual doesn't document `session_path` at all, I'll maybe look if it's an old version.

Comment: My tmux version is 3.0, which seems to be the newest version available in apt. The current version on GitHub is 3.3, so I should probably take a look at building it from source.